# How to create new XML from xpath result with simplexml?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

**Here's my XML-snippet:**

```
<foo>
    <bar>
        <id>120034</id>
        <name>Tom</name>
    </bar>
    <bar>
        <id>9088812</id>
        <name>Tom</name>
    </bar>
    <bar>
        <id>140034</id>
        <name>Mike</name>
    </bar>
</foo>
```

**Here's my PHP** to extract all `bar/name = Tom`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // XML assumed in $x

$results = $xml->xpath("/foo/bar[name = 'Tom']");
```

**Problem:** How to make a new XML from `$results`?

I tried

```
$results->asXML();
```

but I got the error that `$results`is not a simplexml-object.

Comment: xpath results a domnodelist. it's not an xml document itself, just a list/array of nodes that matched the xpath expression. You could extract individual NODES from that list and turn them into xml.

Comment: @MarcB how could that be done?

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop over the result set and do whatever you want with the results.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // XML assumed in $x
$results = $xml->xpath("/foo/bar[name = 'Tom']");
foreach($results as $result) echo $result->asXML();
```